# Using a DELETE FROM Clause with Multiple Conditions and Data From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have two tables. One is a table with price movements, the other is a table with price movements and an adjusted return.

I want to delete data from the price movement table based on data in the return table.

Price movement table looks like this:

```
SecurityID TradeDate  OneDayReturn  
3774978    8/20/2020  -0.0013  
3775071    8/20/2020  -0.0034  
3775156    8/20/2020  -0.027  
3776090    8/20/2020  -0.0012
```

Return table looks like this:

```
SecurityID  TradeDate  OneDayReturn  TodaysIndexSecurityId  IndexReturn TodaysBeta   AdjReturn  
3774978     8/20/2020  -0.0013       21814                  0.0033      0.246153161  0.000812305  
3775071     8/20/2020  -0.0034       14278                  NULL        0.952705801  NULL  
3775156     8/20/2020  -0.027        21814                  0.0033      1.57887578   0.00521029  
3776090     8/20/2020  -0.0012       6859                   NULL        1.478636146  NULL
```

I want to delete a row from pricemovements where ABS(AdjReturn * 2) is greater than ABS(OnedayReturn) but also keep the row if there is a sign flip between OneDayReturn and IndexReturn. So, I'm saying only delete it if OneDayReturn*IndexReturn is positive.

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM #PriceMovements
WHERE (ISNULL( ABS( SELECT AdjReturn * 2 FROM #AdjReturnTable ), 0 ) > 
ABS(OneDayReturn) AND ISNULL(OneDayReturn,0) * ISNULL(IndexReturn,0) > 0);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 129
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'SELECT'.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 129
> Incorrect syntax near
> ')'.

I assume this means that I'm using AND incorrectly or that I can't reference another table in this statement...but is that why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` with `SecurityID` as the common matching column :

```
DELETE p
  FROM #PriceMovements p
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 0
                  FROM #AdjReturnTable 
                 WHERE ISNULL(ABS (AdjReturn * 2), 0) > ABS(OneDayReturn) 
                   AND ISNULL(OneDayReturn, 0) * ISNULL(IndexReturn, 0) > 0
                   AND SecurityID = p.SecurityID );
```

In your case, the SELECT Statement has a wrong place as nested within a function.

Comment: Thank you! When I tried to run this I got "incorrect syntax near p".

Comment: oh my bad, forgot to add something such as a constant(zero) next to SELECT, you're welcome @PolarVortex8

Comment: I copied and pasted again just to make sure, and yes, same error

Comment: OK, SQL Server had an interesting aliasing style for DELETE operation. I added once more  alias `p` @PolarVortex8 or you can alias the table(`#AdjReturnTable a`) within the SELECT statement such as `...AND a.SecurityID = SecurityID` without aliasing `#PriceMovements`.